# How to keep login state in rails 5 API with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I'm using devise for authentication and I can login but can't keep login state.

I post data with postman and I got this response. It seems I logged in.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "dadada",
  "last_name": "dadadada",
  "email": "test@example.com",
  "created_at": "2016-12-19T12:24:59.000+09:00",
  "updated_at": "2016-12-19T17:11:09.000+09:00"
}
```

And next I get UsersController's info action.

```
{
  "error": 'You have to confirm your account before continuing.'
}
```

Is there a way to keep login?

thanks!

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end

end

class Users::UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :json

  def info
    render json: current_user.attributes, status: 200
  end

  def user_entry
  end

end
```

Comment: It looks like you turned on `Device` `Confirmable` module. Have a look here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users

Comment: what url you post this data? maybe you only register the user